# Rotate programmatically UIScrollView content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I've a ScrollView with an UIImageView as subview (fit to margin).

ImageView has an image and some buttons as subviews.

I need to rotate both the image and the buttons (not when device rotate).

Now, rotating image is quite easy:

```
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: image.CGImage scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
```

Rotate also the buttons could be boring, so I would know if there's a way to rotate entire UIScrollView content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `transform` property of UIView. It could do the job, if I understand you right. For example:
`scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);`

Comment: Vladimir is right, but in his code the scroll directions are turned as well. so just turn the `imageView`with his code

Comment: @LoVo is what I need, but why not apply transform to entire scrollView?

Comment: As i said, if you rotate the scrollview, the scroll directions change as well, so you are not scrolling "up" anymore but "right" or "left" could be confusing in some cases. Another example would be; if you want to have a higher scrollview you have to change the width instead because the whole view is turned.

Comment: strange behaviour: after apply transform, I execute this code and the image "come back" to originally orientation. (I try also to invert rotation with this code):     const float minZoom = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.width,
                        self.view.bounds.size.height / self.imageView.image.size.height);
    if (minZoom > 1) {
        return;
    }
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoom;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minZoom;

Answer (score 0):

**Using Swift 4:**

scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)